# Set Read-Only Access for Crystal Report in AlwaysOn environment

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have two SQL servers that are being load balanced - AlwaysOn. Only the second one of these servers is supposed to be used for crystal reports. I would like to access the second SQL server using the `readOnly` flag in the connection string: `ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly`

In my C# class I am running the crystal reports based on `ConnectionInfo()`

```
var myConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();

Tables myTables = reportDocument.Database.Tables;

for (int i = 0; i < myTables.Count; i++)
{
    var myTable = myTables[i];
    var myTableLogonInfo = myTable.LogOnInfo;
    myConnectionInfo.ServerName = 'serverName';
    myConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = 'databaseName';
    myConnectionInfo.UserID = 'userId';
    myConnectionInfo.Password = 'password';
    myTableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo = myConnectionInfo;
    myTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(myTableLogonInfo);
}
```

I haven't found a way to set `ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly` though. Is this supposed to be done setting `myConnectionInfo.Attributes`? Unfortunately I haven't found an answer on this yet but unanswered questions:

- https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3861287
- https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3791155

Comment: What about setting the permissions for `userID` to readonly in the database server?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I did not find a way to use the flag `ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly` in my posted code snippet.

What I ended up doing:
Instead of using the load balancer IP address (or host name), I am using the IP address of the reporting server directly.
I couldn't find any written documentation whether or not one can use `ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly`.

Comment: That is what I am doing on my side. Intelligently changing readonly ServerName in connection string.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using ConnectionInfo, you could use System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder, which has a settable ApplicationIntent property.